# Django installation issues No module named django.core

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install Django on Mac Os X. Following the directions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#installing-development-version

I created a django.pth in the site-packages directory to the trunk folder. However, for some reason Django seems to only work now if I am INSIDE the trunk folder.

If I am anywhere else, if I run `python` and say `import django` 
I get a `No module named django` error.

When I try to run `django-admin.py` I get a `No module named django.core` error.

It works fine if I am inside the trunk directory, if I say `Import Django` here,

I can then say `print django.get_version()` and it works fine.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

print sys.path or PYTHONPATH,

if you see the django path in their you should be able to import it else put it inside sys.path.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you installed it for the right version of Python on your system?

A better (more isolated) way is to use a virtual environment:

```
[~]$ virtualenv --no-site-packages django_env
New python executable in django_env/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
[~]$ source django_env/bin/activate
(django_env)[~]$ pip install -e svn+http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/
Obtaining django from svn+http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/
  Checking out http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/ to ./django_env/src/django
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django

Installing collected packages: django
  Running setup.py develop for django

    Creating /Users/burhan/django_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django.egg-link (link to .)
    Adding Django 1.4b1 to easy-install.pth file
    Installing django-admin.py script to /Users/burhan/django_env/bin

    Installed /Users/burhan/django_env/src/django
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
(django_env)[~]$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 10:35:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
'1.4b1'
```

**[~]$** is the prompt, don't enter this.

Answer (score 1):

Check your installation. Might be you installed in wrong directory. Also check your `PYTHONPATH` and `sys.path`.

```
In [4]: import django

In [5]: django
Out[5]: <module 'django' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc'>
```

This shows that django must be in `site-packages` then you can import from any where. If you installed it in like `/tmp/test/` then add that path in `sys.path` to access the django.

Answer (score 0):

I got it work, not sure how though, it might have been just a typo in my path name. Thanks for your help.